# parseFloat or toFixed not representing decimals

Tags: javascript

Building a calculator with toFixed and parseFloat to represent the digits, it seems to ignore the decimal typing, and when ever you right "." or ".0" or ".00" etc. it skips over until you write a number other than 0. Any help?

```
var ghost = Number(parseFloat(reactant).toFixed(13));
var ghost2 = Number(parseFloat(reactant2).toFixed(13));
var ghostspec = Number(parseFloat(reactantspec).toFixed(13));

 if (vi === 0){
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ghost;
} else if (vi >= 1 && tx === 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ghost2;
} else if (vi >= 1 && tx > 0) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = ghostspec;
}
}
  **this is how you type decimals**
      function click10() {
    if (vi === 0) {
   click10a();
} else if (vi !== 0 && tx === 0) {
   click10b();
 } else if (vi !== 0 && tx !== 0) {
    if (di3 === 0) {
        virs++;
        reactantspec = reactantspec + "" + ".";
        di3++;
    }
}
}
function click10a() {
    if (di1 === 0) {
    reactant = reactant + "" + ".";
    vir++;
    di1++;
    }
}
function click10b() {
    if (di2 === 0) {
    reactant2 = reactant2 + "" + ".";
    vir2++;
    vi++;
    di2++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are using Number(...)? parseFloat already generates a number.

Comment: Would that fix it? Will remove it

Comment: well Number removes the useless trailed zeros

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that the `Number` function truncates the decimals of your formatted number (a String) generated by `parseFloat(...).toFixed(13)`. Take a look:

```js
let wn = Number( parseFloat( "1" ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( "1." ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( ".1" ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( "1.1" ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( "0" ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( "0." ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( ".0" ).toFixed(13) ) + "</br>" +
         Number( parseFloat( "0.0" ).toFixed(13) );

let wtn = parseFloat( "1" ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( "1." ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( ".1" ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( "1.1" ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( "0" ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( "0." ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( ".0" ).toFixed(13) + "</br>" +
          parseFloat( "0.0" ).toFixed(13);

document.getElementById( "result" ).innerHTML = 
       "With Number(...):</br>" + wn + "</br></br>" + 
       "Without Number(...):</br>" + wtn;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: So I see, should I keep it as a string then?

Comment: @Benn yes, since a Number with lots of traling zeroes does not make sense to be a number. `toFixed()` is a formatting function for Numbers.

Comment: But the point of toFixed is to fix up the floating point rounding errors, since it seems to work at 13 decimals or less, I need it to be tofixed to 13 decimals.